# How do I not be a war spectator, but be able to battle in clan wars?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have never been in a clan war before. I've tried, but it doesn't let me. How do I not be a spectator? I want to be in a war.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To not be a spectator, you simply have to be a participant in the war.

To do so, you must ensure the following:

- You are not being excluded by your clan leaders.
  *This can be for a number of reasons, one of them being that the clan has to leave some people out to make a multiple of 5 active players.*
- You are eligible for war.
  *Try not to clan hop half-way through a war.*